# See extended attributes with coreutils ls on Mac

Tags: shell, osx, coreutils, xattr

I have coreutils installed via MacPorts on my Mac running OS X 10.8.4. I have `ls` set to use the coreutils version of `ls` [`(GNU coreutils) 8.21`] when available:

```sh
if [ -e /opt/local/libexec/gnubin ]; then
    alias ls='/opt/local/libexec/gnubin/ls --color=auto'
else
    alias ls='/bin/ls -G'
fi
```

When I run `ls -l` in a directory with files known to have extended attributes (xattrs), I expect to see an `@` sign after the permissions in those listings. However, I see no `@` sign. If I run `/bin/ls -l`, I get the `@` sign.

File listing from `/bin/ls -l`:

```
-rw-r--r--@  1 zev.eisenberg  staff  132887 Jul 19 16:24 flowchart.graffle
```

File listing from `ls -l` (using coreutils):

```
-rw-r--r--  1 zev.eisenberg staff 132887 Jul 19 16:24 flowchart.graffle
```

How can I get the coreutils version of `ls` to show me the `@` sign when xattrs are present?

Comment: Your examples show that coreutils' `ls` shows the `@` and `/bin/ls` does not. Is that correct, or swapped?

Comment: I hate to ruin a good question, but where does zsh enter into the picture? :)

Comment: What's the version of ls + coreutils? `$ ls --version`.

Comment: Michael, it enters because I’m a noob at some of this stuff, and I put in zsh because I use it, and in case it might be relevant :)

Comment: Updated my question with the version: `ls (GNU coreutils) 8.21`.

Comment: Coreutils for OSX isn't built with the same attribute functions, it's made for SELinux (ls -Z on osx shows ?) I'm pretty sure you won't get the same output as the builtin ls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Mark Cohen’s comment is correct: this functionality seems to be absent from the coreutils version of `ls`. I didn’t actually have a good reason to be using coreutils `ls`, so I’ve switched back to the built-in BSD version.

Answer (score 3):

You can add extended attributes to coreutils ls. This is based on coreutils-8.22:

```
***************
*** 59,62 ****
--- 59,64 ----
  #include <wchar.h>

+ #include <sys/xattr.h>
+
  #if HAVE_LANGINFO_CODESET
  # include <langinfo.h>
***************
*** 3056,3059 ****
--- 3058,3062 ----
                              : ACL_T_YES));
            any_has_acl |= f->acl_type != ACL_T_NONE;
+           any_has_acl |= listxattr(f->name, NULL, 0, XATTR_NOFOLLOW);

            if (err)
***************
*** 3811,3814 ****
--- 3814,3819 ----
    if (! any_has_acl)
      modebuf[10] = '\0';
+   else if (listxattr(f->name, NULL, 0, XATTR_NOFOLLOW) > 0)
+     modebuf[10] = '@';
    else if (f->acl_type == ACL_T_SELINUX_ONLY)
      modebuf[10] = '.';
```

Basically I looked in the OS X `ls` source to find the logic for printing the @ (the `listxattr` call) and hooked that into where coreutils `ls` puts a symbol after the permissions. The three changes are:

1. Including `xattr.h`
2. Set `any_has_acl` if any of the listings have extended attributes - this is required so that listings that don't have extended attributes have a space inserted after the permissions to line things up
3. Do the actual check by calling `listxattr` and conditionally setting the `@` symbol - might be worth noting that they way this is written will show only the `@` if there are both extended attributes and ACL

The `XATTR_NOFOLLOW` argument tells `listxattr` not to follow symlinks. That argument is used in OS X `ls`.

Comment: Your answer might be more helpful if you describe the diff you provide.

Comment: This seems useful, but I don’t have a good way to test it. Any chance of submitting a patch to coreutils?

Comment: Would you be able to post the patch here or on GitHub or something?

Comment: Absolutely incredible! This is precisely the patch I needed and can't believe I just found this. I'm going to try compiling this into GNU coreutils 8.32 ls on iOS for jailbroken devices. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @wilywampa I compiled this patch on coreutils 8.22 as you said, but when I use `ls -l` or `ls -lF`, I can see the extra space after -rw--r--r-, but it never displays the @ for xattr, even on /User/Media/DCIM/123APPLE which I can use other tools to confirm all the camera roll contains xattrs. I'm compiling with clang 10 on iOS 12.4 jailbroken, APFS. Any ideas?